# Asking your script to accept arguments which contains whitespace

Tags: shell-script

I'm really stuck on my scripting because of this problem. I need my script to accept arguments and give me the result but since i have spaces it only displays the first word. eg.

```
cat open.sh
echo My name is $1

export start=`date +"%b %d %k:%M:%S %Y"`

[oracle@spiderman scripts]echo $start
Jul 01 3:03:18 2016

[oracle@spiderman scripts]$sh open.sh `echo $start`
The time is Jul
```

I need the output as `The time is Jul 01 3:03:18 2016.`

I need to pass the same output to another complex script.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/117549

Comment: You might also want to use `$@` instead of `$1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use command substitution `$()` around `date` like,

```
export start=$(date +"%b %d %k:%M:%S %Y")
export end=$(date +"%b %d %k:%M:%S %Y")
```

and change `open.sh` with

```
echo The time is "$1" and end time is "$2"
```

(Note : Always quotes your variable, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary))

and run your script with quoted argument like this,

```
$ sh open.sh "$start" "$end"
The time is Jul 01 20:24:03 2016 and end time is Jul 01 22:19:25 2016
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have multiple variables to enter. eg start and end time, so can i do it in this way

Comment: export start=$(date +"%b %d %k:%M:%S %Y")

Comment: @Super Yes, `$@` treats multiple arguments

Comment: export start=$(date +"%b %d %k:%M:%S %Y")
export end=$(date +"%b %d %k:%M:%S %Y")
-- change open.sh with 
echo The start time is "$@"
echo The end time is "$@"
will this work ?

Comment: @Super see my updated answer

Comment: My output is not readable this way..

export start=$(date +"%b %d %k:%M:%S %Y") 
export end=$(date +"%b %d %k:%M:%S %Y")

scripts]$sh open.sh $start $end
the start time is Jul 01 5:20:40 2016 Jul 01 5:20:41 2016
the end time si Jul 01 5:20:40 2016 Jul 01 5:20:41 2016

scripts]$cat open.sh
echo the start time is "$@"
echo the end time si "$@"

Comment: @Super see my updated answer, I have used `$1` & `$2` for first and second argument respectively.

Comment: @Super If that helped you, then please consider accepting answer by clicking on right mark below up/down arrow.

Comment: Hi Rahul,

I works well in a simple script but it fails in my scenario.

the loop i run below goes to multiple database's on different hosts.
for n in `cat $TXTDIR/hostname.txt`
eg:- node1 - dbname (TEST1)
     node2 - dbname (TEST2)

Comment: oswbb]$for n in `cat $TXTDIR/hostname.txt`
> do
> ssh oracle@$n "source $BASEDIR/.setenv; export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/jdk/bin:$PATH; sh /home/oracle/soft/oswbb/name.sh "$start" "$end""
> done
Invalid date: Jul -e 01 -s
Invalid date: 01 -s -A /orasoft/scripts/logs/perf_owatcher_spiderman.glen.log


[oracle@spiderman oswbb]$cat name.sh
java -jar /home/oracle/soft/oswbb/oswbba.jar -i $OSWATCHLOGS -P oswatcher_html_$n -6 -7 -8 -b $1 -e $2 -s -A $LOGDIR/perf_owatcher_`hostname`.log